# psql query count should be global field on condition

Tags: sql, psql

Table schema and data:

```
CREATE TABLE aaa (
    nall integer NOT NULL,
    ladata date NOT NULL,
    txt text,
    CONSTRAINT aaa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (nall, ladata)
 )
```

Data:

```
2 | '2016-01-01' | 'a'
2 | '2016-02-02' | 'a'
5 | '2016-03-03' | 'a'
6 | '2016-03-03' | 'b'
```

Query:

```
select txt,
       count(txt),
       min(ladata),  
       (select  count(txt) from aaa where txt !='') 
from aaa
where ladata > (select MIN(ladata) from aaa ) and nall != 2
group by txt
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/db06b1/1

to return:

> ```
> txt   count   min     count
> b     1   March, 03 2016 00:00:00     1
> a     3   March, 03 2016 00:00:00     3
> ```

I need a partial **count** from row with same **txt** and the date from row with **nall** different from 2.

but keep returning count from entire table:

> ```
> txt   count   min     count
> b     1   March, 03 2016 00:00:00     4
> a     1   March, 03 2016 00:00:00     4
> ```

I'm using postgresql 9.6

Comment: Include the query and data in your question.

Comment: According to `where ladata > (select MIN(ladata) from aaa ) and nall != 2` the query should include 2 records, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
select a.txt, count(a.txt), min(ladata)
    , (select  count(txt) from aaa b where b.txt =a.txt ) 
from aaa a  
where ladata>(select MIN(ladata) from aaa) and nall != 2  
group by txt
```